# how to get the user id of the creator of a reference asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am wondering how can I get the userID of the user that is logged in, fill the form and post it, ie the creator of a reference of my model Client ?

I need it then to retrieve the last record by the user that have push the reference in the database. 
I want to know if there is a method to get the userId of the user that create a reference of my model Client in the create view page ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: is the user logged in? edit your question with more details explaining your problemd and the expected result.

Comment: Yes the user is logged in, I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have logged in user i don't see the problem..Just call

```
Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey
```